# Working with Docker container and large files on host computer

Tags: python, docker, flask, containers

I have a python program that works on very large image files (5GB+).  The program has a flask frontend that allows users to specify the local path to their image file.  The code then runs on that image.

I'm considering using docker to containerize this program.  However, I'm not sure how best to work with large files on the host computer from within a container.  I know I could mount the entire c: drive to the directory on the container (linux).  I can then append the user-specified path to that directory within the container.

For Example:

I mount c: to /base_dir within container

The User specifies path, e.g. c:\Users\dave\Desktop\large_image_file

My code will then look for the image file here:

/base_dir/Users/dave/Desktop/large_image_file

Is there a better way to handle this?

I want to avoid asking users upload file to the container and it seems inefficient

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If the program principally works on local files, you'll probably find it much easier to run without Docker.